# Text replacement

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup

I have a small business that uses Google Sheets to track our employee's cases. When they are typing in that they are handling a case they just put their initials. I would like to make use of the Reminders addon to make sure that cases are not forgotten. The Reminders addon requires that an email be given with who to contact so that it can send them an email reminder. However it is faster to simply type the initials of the case worker.

How to manipulate the functions or write a custom one so that all initials in a certain column can be replaced with the corresponding email?

For example:

```
=IF(B2="ABC", SUBSTITUTE(B2,"ABC","ABC@123.com"))
```

Will place ABC's email if the initials `ABC` are found in a new cell. However I can't expand the function to replace all the employees initials in one script as IFELSE is not recognized as a valid function.

Comment: You can string many if statements together.  the if function relies on the following order `=If(condition,if true do this, if false do this)`.  To string together multiple if statements place another if formula in the place where the if false do this is. Like so...`=IF(B2="ABC", SUBSTITUTE(B2,"ABC","ABC@123.com"),IF(B2="DEF", SUBSTITUTE(B2,"DEF","DEF@123.com")))` etc...

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a simple vlookup

Make a new sheet with two columns. The first containing the initals the second containing the email addresses.

In a new column in sheet1 you would then write somethign like this:
        =vlookup(B2,Sheet2!A1:B25,2)
Where B2 is the cell with the initials and Sheet2!A1:B25 is the range where you store the email addresses.